# Can I host minikube remotely for development in a team?

Tags: kubernetes, remote-server, minikube

Can I start minikube on a remote dedicated server to develope and test kubernetes with my team?
For now we didn‘t want to make a real 3 node cluster to safe money and I only can find information about minikube running for locally development.

Comment: Minikube runs a single-node Kubernetes for local, you can setup kubernetes.

Comment: so hosting apps in development state can be accessed from outside the minikube host?

Comment: wait now I'm irritated, so does that for example mean I can start a website container in minikube on server in a datacenter and access it via my browser from my pc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minikube is only designed for local development. You need to deploy a Kubernetes cluster using something like [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm/)